# fade in/out animation in java while changing jframe

Tags: java, swing, fadein, fadeout

I want fade in and fade out transition when changing jframe in java Swing. I have added one library called nefanimation. but my code is not running correct. Please help me. 
This is my code:

```
info in = new info();
in.show();
Fade.JFrameFadeIn(1f, 0f, 0.1f, 60, this , Fade.);
this.hide();
```

Comment: your code does not compile: " Fade.);"  is missing something. 

what exceptions do you get?

Comment: bassically i just want to change jframe1 to another jframe2 animationally like  jframe1 will fadeout and then fadein jframe2. does someone have any type of code??

Comment: you need to provide compilable code, nobody will write code for you

Comment: boss thanks alot i have done it